# How to programmatically switch a switch in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I make us several [Switch Components](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch.html) in one view. When I switch on one switch, I want all others to switch off. Currently, I set the boolean `value` property via the state. This results in changes happen abruptly because the switch is just re-rendered and not transitioned.

So how would you switch them programmatically?

**EDIT 2**: I just discovered that it runs smoothly on Android so it looks like an iOS-specific problem.

**EDIT**: part of the code

```
  _onSwitch = (id, switched) => {
    let newFilter = { status: null };

    if (!switched) {
      newFilter = { status: id };
    }
    this.props.changeFilter(newFilter); // calls the action creator
  };

  _renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const switched = this.props.currentFilter === item.id; // the state mapped to a prop
    return (
      <ListItem
        switchButton
        switched={switched}
        onSwitch={() => this._onSwitch(item.id, switched)}
      />
    );
  };
```

Comment: post your code...

Comment: Can you share your code pls

Comment: It's not about my code. It works correctly. I just about the transition, but I will try to make a minimal example. It's not that easy because of all the redux stuff etc.